# How to read data of a certain length in text file and store in an integer array in matlab

Tags: matlab, textscan

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
777
3
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The first two lines are the dimensions of the data, for this particular example there are 3 rows of data and 777 columns (or values in each row).

I need to read in this data into Matlab and store the result as an integer array. 
ie. My array would be 3 rows x 777 columns and look like this:

```
H = [
1 0 0 0 ...
0 1 0 0 ...
0 0 1 0 ...
]
```

I'm having problems reading in the data using the specific dimensions and also picking off the first two values from the file. What I did to try and read just the data and not the dimensions was just deleted the first two lines but I would prefer to not do this. I pasted the code I have tried below, I tried two different methods without getting the desired result:

```
% Method 1
H = textread('myTextFile.txt', '%s');
ncols = size(H, 1);
nrows = size(H{1}, 2);
H = reshape(sscanf([H{:}], '%1d'), ncols,nrows);

% Method 2
fid = fopen('myTextFile.txt', 'r');
H = textscan(fid,'%777s');
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`fopen`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html), [`feof`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/feof.html), [`fgetl`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html), [`str2double`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html) and  two loops, to design a piece of code that suits your specific problem:

```
% Open file.
fid = fopen('myTextFile.txt', 'r');
% Initialize row index for H.
a = 1;
% Initialize number of line counter for file.
nline = 1;
% Test for end-of-file.
while ~feof(fid)
    % Read line from file as string.
    line = fgetl(fid);
    % Test for number of line geater than 2.
    if(nline > 2)
        % Loop through every character from the string.
        % b is column index for H.
        for b = 1:length(line)
            % Extract char from the string, convert it to double and store it in H.
            H(a, b) = str2double(line(b));
        end
        % Increase row index for H.
        a = a + 1;
    end
    % Increase number of line counter.
    nline = nline + 1;
end
% Close file.
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code I made that reads lines from a file and stores them into an integer array:

```
string str = "";
string str2 = ""; // To store load address for .

// myfile.open(argv[1]); // opening file
ifstream read1; // iostream variable named read1
file1.open(argv[1]);
// Memory will initialize itself by reading a program file.

cout << "File name: " << argv[1] << endl;
if(file1.is_open()) {
    cout << "File Open!" << endl;
}
while(file1.good()) // Read till end of file
{
    getline(file1, str); // Read string
    //cout << str << endl;

    if(isdigit(str[0]))
    {
        number[c++] = atoi(str.c_str()); // write(address, data) - writes 
                                         // the data to the address
    }
}
```